# Hiding document label placeholders

Tags: information-management

I'm using Labels as part of an information management policy, to display fields in Microsoft Office documents.  The fields used are:

- Protection Level (required choice field with values "Not Protected", "Protect-Low", "Protect-Medium", "Protect-High")
- Caveat (optional text field allowing a description to be added e.g. "Until 01/01/2020"

When I add the label to a Word document it works nicely e.g.

> Protect-Medium Until 01/01/2020

However, if no value is provided for the caveat field, the label placeholder is displayed when printed:

> Not Protected {Caveat}

Is it possible to hide that placeholder?  Any suggestions for workarounds if it's not possible?

Comment: I am thinking that the placeholder exists to prompt the users for the input. But labels are useful when the document is printed and the placeholder will not appear when it is printed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey, I agree that the placeholders are good to prompt users for input, however they're appearing when printed on paper or to PDF. Is this different to your experience?